# Node.js -> MySQL wont execute JOIN command

Tags: mysql, node.js

I cant seem to get MySQL to spit out the information from my database, I have entered the same query through command line as well as phpmyadmin and the both execute fine, only when I attempt to run it through node server it sends me the error below,

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Meetings.user' in 'field list'
```

This is the code I am running,

```
var options = {sql:'SELECT users.username, `Meetings`.`user` FROM Meetings INNER JOIN users on `Meetings`.`user` = users.id', nestTables:true};
    pool.query(options, function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(module_name + err)//Debugging purposes
      }else{
        console.log(rows);//Debugging purposes
      }
    })
```

I have tried playing around with the quotes using many variations although I either receive an empty object or an error message.

I have read the documentation available for this module, but have still had no luck.
[mysql-Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#joins-with-overlapping-column-names)

I don't no if i'm missing something or just doing it completely wrong, either way help would be much appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Note: all my other queries work fine, only the JOIN query seems to be giving me issues.

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the same database? If it says there's no column, there is probably no column, so you may have a secondary database with a similar but non-identical schema.

Comment: Try with this implicit JOIN query, if this doesn't work then you'll know that the JOIN is not the problem. "SELECT users.username, Meetings.user FROM Meetings, users where Meetings.user = users.id;"

Comment: Thanks both your answers help me determine the problem, I was updating a local copy of the database and forgot to update the database the file was connecting to thus 'Meetingss.user' did not exist because it was named 'Meetings.userID'. @Gepser